# creating a new column by counting element in range of rows using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a permutation that contains WL for each Match as follow:

```
N_Match = 3
data = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product("WL", repeat=N_Match)))
```

Since I used N_match = 3 the output of dataframe will have 3 columns:
I would like to count number of **W** and **L** for each row in all columns.
I will create a new column as follow:
If number of W is greater than no. of L, the formula that i will use for the cell is 1/2^(N_Match), else 0

HOw can I create that column as shown in the following sample:

[image]

in this case, 0.125 is calculated as 1/2^N_Match,
Thanks in advance for the advice.
Regards,

Zep

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with count number of matched values by `sum` of `True`s values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
mask = data.eq('W').sum(axis=1) > data.eq('L').sum(axis=1)
data['Prob'] = np.where(mask, 1/2**(N_Match), 0)
print (data)
   0  1  2   Prob
0  W  W  W  0.125
1  W  W  L  0.125
2  W  L  W  0.125
3  W  L  L  0.000
4  L  W  W  0.125
5  L  W  L  0.000
6  L  L  W  0.000
7  L  L  L  0.000
```